# Splash screen when the site is open on a mobile device - How

Tags: asp.net, css, mobile, splash-screen

What is the standard way of implementing the splash screen that is shown when the web site is open from a mobile device? I mean the screen that has links to the native apps and an option to continue to the full site.

I am thinking of using http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ to detect the client browser on the server (C#, ASP.NET) and maybe redirect the user to a special page.

Alternatively, I can have a modal popup or something that is hidden by default and only shown with CSS3 media queries.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at 51Degrees.mobi ? http://51degrees.com/ I've used this for device detection and it's pretty accurate.